# Creating a UI component library with react-native for android apps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg

I want to use my UI components as a reusable seperate repo/project for my `react-native iniit` App.
So i creatd a seperate project folder like this

[image]

and installed these dependencies

[image]

and few dependencies externally with my other app.

Then i used

> yarn link

to link this project to my working app as a module just like a node module. but i get this error when i try to run my app?

[image]

Is there an issue with my method, or is there a sure way i can try to reach my goal because i found multiple ways and various configuration of creating such component libraries.but i didn't use any since the end goal is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the React Native packager.  See this discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/637.

This may have to do with using watchman, although there seem to be a few different cases where this can crop up.

TL;DR: React Native packager does not respect symlinks to projects, so npm and yarn link do not work like you would expect them to.  Apparently this is being resolved in metro-bundler:  https://github.com/facebook/metro-bundler/issues/1.

Unfortunately the workarounds are not that pretty, but there are a few options discussed in the issue 637 discussion.  It also looks like you may be using a github repo for your package.

You could tell npm to get your library from github via your project's package.json, so you probably do not need npm link, though you will not be able to link to your local files for your module this way.

Comment: Yes, i am heading that direction.Thank you :)